# Redis Sentinels with TLS

Tags: ssl, redis, sentinel

Is Redis 4.x compatible with running TLS with Sentinels? I've found some threads mentioning support for TLS would be added to 3.2, but nothing confirming.

Comment: Please share link to the other threads, that way we won't be repeating what you have already researched.

Comment: Ok so allegedly Redis now supports TLS. I'm trying to get Sentinels to work using stunnel. Note that replication between masters and slaves works.

Answer (score 2):

No, Redis in general and Sentinel in particular do not provide native TLS yet (as of and including v4.0.8). You can, with varying degrees of effort and success, implement security yourself.